# Python selenium ignore text format?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have a problem when I try to match a name between my `name` string and the name in a webelement.

For example:

Name format in my `name`string (scraped from a web site): Mcburnie

Name in webelement: Mc**B**urnie

Since the webelement has a different format (capital B) the Xpath matching fails.

This is my code:

```
choose_player = init_webdriver.wait.until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                                (
                                    By.XPATH,
                                    (
                                        "//span[@class='btn-text' and contains(text(),'"
                                        + name # = Mcburnie in our example
                                        + "')]"
                                    ),
                                )
                            )
                        )
```

As long as the name is standard like "Benny" or "Smith" its all ok.
I also formatted my `name` string with `.title()` so I get a capital letter first but I dont know how to handle such a case above.

Any idea how I can get it working that the elemten gets clicked when the text format is different?

Comment: Did the answers below solve your issue? If yes, please accept/vote, so this thread is not left unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python replace as well,

```
name = 'Mcburnie'
new_name = name.replace('b', 'B')
print(new_name)
```

should print `McBurnie` and then you can parse this into the xpath. also if you can have a or clause in xpath like :

```
//*[contains(text(),'Mcburnie') or contains(text(), 'McBurnie')]
```

you can have n number of or clause.

**Update 1 :**

You can do this, when you scrape a web element from UI, try to store in a variable :

```
var = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "some xpath to get the UI element").text
ui_text_in_lower_case = var.lower()

your_string_in_local = "soMe stringSS"
local_text_in_lower_case = your_string_in_local.lower()
```

Also, if you can have a xpath without text, in place of `some xpath to get the UI element` do not hardcode text, that is not recommended at all.

Comment: the name was just an example and it can be any name so I can not hardcode it. The porblem only comes up ith names with like 2 capital letters in it like McBurnie

Comment: @exec85 :  See the update above, I think that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
choose_player = init_webdriver.wait.until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.XPATH, (
      "//span[@class='btn-text' and contains(lower-case(.),'"
      + name.lower() # = Mcburnie in our example
      + "')]"
      ),
    )
  )
 )
```

Comment: not working unfortunately. Also when I change (.) to text()

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `translate` function.

Exact value:

```
"//span[@class='btn-text' and translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" +name.lower() +"']"
```

Or using `contains` function combination:

```
"//span[@class='btn-text' and contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" +name.lower() +"')]"
```